# Django overriding display names for foreign key field in modelform

Tags: python, django

Suppose below models:

```
from django.db import models


class Status:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article:
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I want to create admin form for `Article` model, but don't want to use results of `__str__` method of `Status` model as display name in status choices form field. It can be achieved by  overriding `label_from_instance` method `ModelChoiceField` as below:

```
from django import forms

from blog.models import Status, Article

class StatusModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, status):
        label = f"{status.order}: {status.name}"

        return label

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    status = StatusModelChoiceField(queryset = Status.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('headline', 'status')
```

Problem with this method is that, it doesn't take into account `Article` model's `status` field definition. For example, although `status` field is nullable in `Article` model, it is required in `ArticleForm`. I should tell explicitly that it is not required (`status = StatusModelChoiceField(queryset = Status.objects.all(), required=False)`). If `status` field would have `limit_choices_to`, it also won't be considered in my form dynamically.

So, I just want different display names than default `__str__`. How can I achieve this goal in more **DRY** manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you will have to make the custom field inheriting from `ModelChoiceField`, what you can do is set it as the class to be used for your field by using the `field_classes` attribute one can set on the forms `Meta` (Reference [Overriding the default fields [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)):

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('headline', 'status')
        field_classes = {
            'status': StatusModelChoiceField,
        }
```